# What are the new PHP "MongoDB's" alternative for legacy "Mongo's" skip() and limit() functions?

Tags: php, mongodb, pagination

As mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php), PHP's `Mongo` extension/driver is now deprecated, and the new counterpart is `MongoDB` driver, which has a [related PHP library named PHPLib](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php).

Now the old Mongo extension had `MongoCursor.skip()` and `MongoCursor.limit()` functions. I could use them for pagination.

But now, apparently the new MongoDB's (or the related library's) cursor does not have `skip()` or `limit()` functions. To know how I found out that, [see my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471570/error-implementing-simple-pagination-with-skip-and-limit-in-mongodb-php-driv).

My question is that, what are the alternatives of skip() and limit() functions (for implementing pagination) then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as options of Query constructor:

```
$filter = [];
$options = [
    'limit' => //integer,
    'skip' => //integer
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
```

**[Edit]**

I just answer your other question.